# Network Output Buffering

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, client-server, output-buffering, trafficshaping

How can I hold the packets generated from a server until an external signal is delievered. On receiving the signal the host hosting the server should release the packets?

I think it can be done with `qdisc` module in kernel but i don't know how to use it specifically for this case. a simple working example is required.

Any other way is also fine.

Comment: I'm also looking for this answer :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Network-packets buffering in kernel qdiscs module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64164254/network-packets-buffering-in-kernel-qdiscs-module)

Comment: @f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534 yes that helped in fact that is the answer to this question, now i think i'll change this question to get another answer where the buffering can be done based on port connections, like if there is any way we can buffer the packets based on port on which the server is running.

Comment: @f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534 like how wireshark tool access the packets to make analyses, in my case i have to get more control over the outgoing traffic to buffer it.(this is just an idea, don't know if it's possible).

Comment: Ok good. I don't know how port-based buffering could be done unfortunately. Maybe iptables could be used to separate the traffic based on the port.